# Makefile dependency by file content, which might not exist

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make

I am having a problem creating Makefile build that has dependency of some other file content.

I know that I can write something like that in makefile to generate prerequisites on-the-fly:

```
result/nuclease.stat : $(shell cat config/nuclease.sample.list)

#bash
make result/nuclease.stat
```

But the problem is that the file *config/nuclease.sample.list* might not exist and I have a target for it.

If I could force make to require *config/nuclease.sample.list* before *$(shell cat config/nuclease.sample.list)* gets evaluated - problem is solved.

What kind of dependency I should make?

One more thing, I would like keep all gnu make's good qualities: download files only once, process them only once and etc..

Please check [image: Makefile dependency tree]

Answer (score 5):

The most straightforward answer is to use [constructed include files](http://make.mad-scientist.net/constructed-include-files/).  In this method you'd include a makefile that defined the dependency relationships you wanted, and provide a make rule that generated that included file with the information you want.  That's all you have to do: make knows how to do the rest.  Based on your question it might be something like:

```
include nuclease-sample-list.mk

nuclease-sample-list.mk: config/nuclease.sample.list
        echo "result/nuclease.stat : $$(cat $<)" > $@
```

That's all you have to do.  If you're using an older version of GNU make you might need to use `-include` instead of `include` to avoid seeing warning messages.